# Syntax error for expression

Tags: expression, after-effects

I am pulling my hair out with this problem.  I am trying to use a separate file that contains strings to fill out certain information in my After Effects comp.

Here is the contents of my file right now (for testing):

```
var Comp1TitleLayer = "Some Text";
var Comp1SubTitleLayer = "Some More Text";
```

Now, I am attempting to use the following expression in the TitleLayer's `Source Text`:

```
var myPath = "~/Desktop/source.txt";
$.evalFile(myPath);
try {
    eval(thisComp.name + thisLayer.name);
} catch (err) {
    "Missing";
}
```

Now, I get the following error when the expression is run:

```
Error at line 1 in property 'Source Text' of layer 1 ('TitleLayer') in comp 'Comp1'.  Syntax error.
```

All the examples I see online give this expression.  I also tried this:

```
#include "~/Desktop/source.txt";
eval(thisCompl.name + thisLayer.name);
```

But I get the same error.  Am I just doing something totally wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If that's what is in your text file (and it is un-formatted text), you are instantiating two variables, and it works as if you did that in your expression. Therefore you can do:

```
 $.evalFile("~/Desktop/source.txt");
"First variable: " + Comp1TitleLayer + "\r" + 
"Second variable: " + Comp1SubTitleLayer;
```

and it should work (as it does on my machine).

In your try block, you don't need eval (but you also aren't using your data in your file):

```
var myPath = "~/Desktop/source.txt";
$.evalFile(myPath);
try {
    thisComp.name + thisLayer.name;
} catch (err) {
    "Missing";
}
```

This shows how to use evalFile() and why you might be getting "Missing", but not why you might be getting a syntax error. Are you sure that is un-formatted text and not rtf or something?

**[EDIT]**
So it turns out there is a problem with this on Mavericks (my original post was using OSX 10.6.8). If you use this construction, it works (assuming the code in source.txt is valid, of course):

```
var myPath = "~/Desktop/source.txt";
try {
 $.evalFile(myPath);
} catch (err) {
    "Missing";
    }
try {
    thisComp.name + thisLayer.name;
} catch (err) {
    "Missing";
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with running this code on the OS X.  I run the code that I provided on my Windows computer and it works just fine (as does the code that you provided).  Nothing runs properly on my Mac, and other people have sought out help with this same issue on Macs, so I am leaving it alone (after reporting to Adobe about it) and doing this on my Windows PC.  Thanks.

Comment: See **[EDIT]** for code that works with Mavericks and Pre-Mavericks OSX.